# How to retrieve/find with specific text on tweet from user timeline twitter with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, mysql-python, tweepy

I'm trying to get specific tweet from user timeline with contain text "#Gempa" using python

i am able to get user timeline, but i want to get the timeline with text just contain "#Gempa" or something specific text

here is my code

```
#Import the necessary methods from tweepy library
import tweepy, codecs
import pymysql
import time

#Variables that contains the user credentials to access Twitter API 
access_token = "XXX"
access_token_secret = "XXX"
consumer_key = "XXX"
consumer_secret = "XXX"

#Authentication
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Declare Connection
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port='', user='root', passwd='', db='test', use_unicode=True, charset="utf8mb4")
cur = conn.cursor()

#Get Current Date Time
curdatetime = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

cur.execute("DELETE FROM tweet order by id desc LIMIT 500")

#Get last id from table tweet
last_id = 0
cur.execute("SELECT MAX(id) FROM tweet")
result = cur.fetchall()
for row in result:
    last_id = row[0]
    print ("Last ID : " + str(last_id))

#Get Number of Tweet
user = api.get_user(108543358)
print ("Name:", user.name)
print ("Name:", user.screen_name)
print ("Number of tweets: " + str(user.statuses_count))
print ("followers_count: " + str(user.followers_count))
print ("Account location: ", user.location)
print ("Account created at: ", user.created_at)


n = 0
for Tweet in tweepy.Cursor(api.user_timeline, id=108543358, q = "#Gempa", lang = id, result_type = "recent", since_id = last_id).items(3):
    print ("*****" + str(i) +"*****")
    print ("ID: " + Tweet.id_str)
    print ("Text: " + str(Tweet.text.encode("utf-8")))
    print ("Retweet Count: " + str(Tweet.retweet_count))
    print ("Favorite Count: " + str(Tweet.favorite_count))
    print ("Date Time: " + str(Tweet.created_at))
    #print (str(Tweet.location)) #how to get geolocation data for mapping ?
    print ("************")

    n = n + 1
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO tweet (no, id, text, retweet_count, favourite_count, date_time) VALUES (%s, %s,%s,%s,%s,%s)",
    (str(n), Tweet.id_str, Tweet.text.encode("utf-8"), str(Tweet.retweet_count), str(Tweet.favorite_count), str(Tweet.created_at)))


conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

and the result is

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YwBya.png)

i can't get user timeline with specific text, anyone can solve this, thanks before

Comment: Are you serious ? remove your tokens for security reasons !

Comment: ooh man, thanks again to remind me about token. i newbie about this, sorry :(

Comment: great advices sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there are no "q", "lang", "result_type" parameters for API.user_timeline (read http://docs.tweepy.org/en/v3.5.0/api.html#API.user_timeline)

So to ignore some tweets, you have to code a filter. You just can skip tweets not containing "#Gempa" like this :

```
for Tweet in api.user_timeline(user_id=108543358):
    text = str(Tweet.text.encode("utf-8"))
    if "#Gempa" not in text:
        continue
    print ("*****" + str(n) +"*****")
    print ("ID: " + Tweet.id_str)
    ...
```

Comment: thanks about ur response, i really aprecciate that.

but in python, code "not in" it must exactly same with the text
i used it "not in" on another case text mining
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50480787/give-relevance-score-to-my-result-text-mining-with-my-set-define-text-using-py

and i got nothing for the result. i need code like to filter the text only contain "#Gempa", any other solution ?

Comment: oh noo, it was a great answer. 
i just changed "#Gempa" with 'Gempa', and it works

thanks for answer @JeffProd, problem solve now.

Comment: great answer sir